# AWS log management for videos and audios

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm looking for a log application that gives a human readable overview of streaming videos and audios via AWs. 
I know there are various log management tools available that can read the log files in a bucket, but most seems to concentrate on advanced services like EC2 etc.
I just need a tool that tells me how many times a video or audio is played in a day/week/month.
Does anyone know a good application/service for this?

Thanks,
Rudolf+++

Comment: As this is normally expensive to calculate, AWS would never provide such a tool. Ideally, you would create or use any existing tool yourself. To do it, you would need to locate a logfile where there are requests to videos. Once you got the logfile, you can ingest it into a database, and you need to have appropriate performance in that (ideally buffered ingest). Once you have logs ingested, and ideally rotated, you need to render HTML page with the stats. Most free tools doesn't support logfile columns for videos, and are inaccurate with the HTTP codes as well (as there are some differences).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but that seems like an awful lot of work and beyond my expertise.
I'm looking for an application that already exists, whether it is from AWS or a third party does not matter to me.

Comment: Sawmill can fetch logs and produce reports for Streaming Video. It's really simple small app with database included. http://www.sawmill.co.uk/. I did one deployment for 10M daily unique viewers using pretty much small server.

Comment: That looks more like it, Andrew. :-)
Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried Sawmil out, but it is too complicated for my customers to be useful.

Comment: Then you can try AWStats. You can tune the log format and various configuration options to get the desired result. If you need a specific report for billing, you might want to develop software to ingest log into database and produce report via email/html.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew but AWStats does not give specific information about videos and this is not something a non technical customer can install easily. I'm looking for an easy to use online solution.  You pay a monthly fee, you tell the online application where to find the logs and off you go.
There are many out there, but most do not deal specifically with videos and audios.